# Can't change a string back to an integer in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, int

```
def get_time():
    start_time = str(input("Please enter the time you started working (hh:mm) "))
    if ":" in start_time:
        h1, m1 = start_time.split(":")
    else:
        h1 = int(start_time)
        m1 = " "
    if h1 < 8:
        print("You can't start working until 08:00.")
    elif h1 > 23:
        print("You can't work past 24:00 (midnight) ")
    end_time = str(input("Please enter the time you stopped working (hh:mm) "))

get_time()
```

Here's my code for a program I'm making to take in the times someone babysitted. I'm having trouble turning the string numbers back into an integer. I get the error:

```
  File "/Applications/Python 3.4/babysitting.py", line 10, in get_time
    if h1 < 8:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Why isn't `h1 = int(start_time)` working?

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't `h1 = int(start_time)` working?

That line isn't being executed at all when you have a `:` character in the input:

```
if ":" in start_time:
    h1, m1 = start_time.split(":")
else:
    h1 = int(start_time)
    m1 = " "
```

The `int(start_time)` is executed *only* when there is no `:` in the input, so when the `if` test is false.

Separate the splitting and the integer conversion:

```
h1 = start_time
if ":" in start_time:
    h1 = start_time.split(":")[0]
h1 = int(h1)
```